# VBScript Error Accessing Active Directory

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

OK, I surrender. I'm working on scripting some data from Active Directory and I've hit a bug I just can't figure out. My script is;

```
'On Error Resume Next
Option Explicit

dim objConnection
dim objCommand
dim objRecordset

Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE 

objCommand.CommandText = _
"SELECT Name, description, distinguishedName, member FROM     'LDAP://ou=mybusiness,dc=huntfamily,dc=local' WHERE objectCategory='group'"  
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

objRecordSet.MoveFirst
Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value  '   & "," & _
    Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("description").Value
    Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("member").Value

    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

I"m getting an error of C:\Bin\SecurityGroupt.vbs(26, 2) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch

This is on the line;

```
Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("description").Value
```

Using Active Directory Explorer from Sysinternals, I see the value called description and it says it is a DirectoryString. Anything that I try to do with that value, treating it as a string, gives this error. I tried casting it to a string and got the same thing.

There must be something I am missing. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the output of `WScript.Echo TypeName(objRecordSet.Fields("description").Value)`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("Description").Value
```

try

```
If (isnull(objRecordSet.Fields("Description").Value)) Then
  Wscript.Echo "Description not defined"
Else
  Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("Description").Value
End If
```

or

```
strDescription = objRecordSet.Fields("Description").Value
If IsNull( strDescription) Then
  Wscript.Echo "Description not defined"
Else
  Wscript.Echo strDescription
End If
```

!!! in the last case do not forget to define strDescription variable in advance:

```
Dim strDescription
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion. The result is the Else code is run and I get the same error. So apparently it's not null.

Comment: @Bernie try 'IsEmpty' function instead of 'IsNull' one. Follow Ansgar's advice: 'WScript.Echo TypeName( objRecordSet.Fields( "description").Value)'

Answer (score 0):

If the field contains an array you could [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) the array elements:

```
WScript.Echo Join(objRecordSet.Fields("description").Value, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time but just in case...

Try this instead:

```
On Error Resume Next

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value  '   & "," & _
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Value not defined"
        Err.Clear
    End If
    Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("description").Value
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Value not defined"
        Err.Clear
    End If
    Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Value not defined"
        Err.Clear
    End If
    Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("member").Value
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Value not defined"
        Err.Clear
    End If
    objRecordSet.MoveNext       
Loop

On Error Goto 0
```

There are cleaner ways to do it but I am working from memory.